# Flutter Streams usage

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

How to create stream and use it with StreamBuilder().
I need to stream External Storage Directory in real time like as Firebase Cloud Firestore and get info if storage have current file which I search. For example, I have videos or images which I downloaded from my application, and want to listen external storage directory to show files in real time. And when I delete any file it removes from screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StreamBuilder` widget is really useful for such cases, you can check the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

First of all, what is a stream? Imagine it like a tube, where things are passed in one side of the tube, asynchronously (meaning not all items are passed at the same time); and, at some point of the future, those items arrive at the other end of the tube, again, asynchronously.

Now, knowing what a `Stream` is, we have to realise that we do not know when our request will end, it may never end! Therefore, Flutter provides us with the `StreamBuilder` widget. Let's say that your Firebase instance returns a `Stream<List<Item>>` named `getListOfItems`. Using the `StreamBuilder`, you could do:

```dart
//... As a child of any of your widgets
StreamBuilder(
  stream: instance.getListOfItems(), // <-- We simply pass the function that returns the stream, Flutter will manage the rest!
  builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
    // The snapshot contains the data that is being recieved if any
    // you can check the docs:
    // https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html
    // And for the ConnectionState enum
    // https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      // What should be rendered when loading or waiting for a response?
      return Loading();
    } 

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // What should be rendered when there's data?
      // Remember, data may keep arriving
      return MyList(snapshot.data);
    }

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // Wow, the stream failed, what should be rendered when there's an error?
      return Error();
    }
  }
)
```

That should do for any basic implementation of the `StreamBuilder`. From here you can build dynamic lists, pagination and more!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I didn't ask about Firebase, I need to create Stream of External Storage Directory when I keep some files.

Comment: That is independent. You can use the example for your external storage directory. You would only need it to return a `Stream` of something.

Comment: Do I need to put setState inside Stream to Update state if data changed?

Comment: Do you need to keep the list of items as part of your state?

Comment: I need to show current info, if file deleted, list on my screen should be updated, if new file added,  list on my screen should be updated again and so on like as Firestore real time changes.

Comment: Any updates one the would also update the stream, and therefore there's no need to keep it in the state (and I would not recoend either).

Comment: Does it mean that I should put setState in Stream creating function? For example: Stream<double> getRandomValue() {
    var random = Random();
   setState(() {});
    yield random.nextDouble();
  }
I see if I don't put setState inside, value doesn't update on screen, but when I put setState it does

Comment: No. If you delete an item from that list, it will be deleted to the database, wouldn't it? Then, as it is a stream, the api would notify the active stream and it would re-render again.

Comment: can you write example, please? I can't understand as well :(

Comment: You should check more information about streams and reactive programming before going too deep into it. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE) from the Flutter channel.